# automake third party libraries

Tags: c++, gnu, autotools, automake

How to compile and link third party libraries with automake?

My file structure is:

```
program/
  |
  +--src/
  |   |
  |   +--Makefile.am
  |   +--main.cpp
  |
  +--lib/
  |   |
  |   +--Makefile.am
  |   +--library.cpp
  |
  +--Makefile.am
  +--configure.ac
  +--README
```

Contents of automake files are pretty generic:

```
# src/Makefile.am
bin_PROGRAMS = program
program_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

---

```
# Makefile.am
SUBDIRS = src lib
dist_doc_DATA = README
```

---

```
# configure.ac
AC_INIT([program], [1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile lib/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

What should be the contents of `lib/Makefile.am`?

Comment: Just to add to @chrono's answer, `SUBDIRS` lists directories with depth-first descent. Since the `src` depends on `lib` build, considers setting: `SUBDIRS = lib src`. You can even add the `.` directory to direct the order of processing relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

*(Not sure why you said "third-party" when you appear to have control of the library code yourself... For more info related to creating and working with libraries using Automake, I refer you to the [GNU Automake manual's section on libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/A-Library.html))*

**lib/Makefile.am**

```
lib_LIBRARIES = libYOURLIB.a
libYOURLIB_a_SOURCES = library.cpp
```

You can use `noinst_lib_LIBRARIES` if you don't want to install the library itself. Note that I'm assuming you want to build a static library only. See the [Building A Shared Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/A-Shared-Library.html) section of the GNU Automake manual for integrating with Libtool to produce a shared library. You can do it manually of course, but it's a lot easier with Libtool as it takes care of various platform differences.

To link your library to `program`, you'd add the following lines in
**src/Makefile.am**:

```
program_DEPENDENCIES = $(top_builddir)/lib/libYOURLIB.a
program_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/lib/libYOURLIB.a
```

The `_DEPENDENCIES` line simply tells Automake that `program` relies on `lib/libYOURLIB.a` being built first, and the `_LDADD` line simply adds the library to the linker command.

---

The above assumes that you have a rule to build the library already. Since you're using `SUBDIRS`, you received a "no rule to make target XXXXXX" build failure, which indicates that you don't (at least from the perspective of the Makefile in the `src` subdirectory). To remedy this, you can try the following in **src/Makefile.am** (taken from ["Re: library dependency"](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2009-03/msg00011.html) on the GNU Automake mailing list archives):

```
FORCE:

$(top_builddir)/lib/libYOURLIB.a: FORCE
<TAB>(cd $(top_builddir)/lib && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) libYOURLIB.a)
```

You can also simply make `lib` a subdirectory of `src` as your comment indicated of course and make it simpler.

Alternatively, you can stop using a recursive build setup and use what is perhaps a simpler non-recursive build setup. See [GNU Automake Manual §7.3: An Alternative Approach to Subdirectories](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Alternative.html#Alternative) and [Non-recursive Automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) for some information on that, but the general idea would be to alter things to allow for :

**configure.ac**

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall subdir-objects])
...
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
# Instead of using the SUBDIRS variable.
include src/Makefile.am.inc
include lib/Makefile.am.inc
dist_doc_DATA = README
```

**lib/Makefile.am** renamed to **lib/Makefile.am.inc**

```
# Full path relative to the top directory.
lib_LIBRARIES = lib/libYOURLIB.a
lib_libYOURLIB_a_SOURCES = lib/library.cpp
```

**src/Makefile.am** renamed to **src/Makefile.am.inc**

```
# Full path relative to the top directory.
bin_PROGRAMS = bin/program
bin_program_SOURCES = src/main.cpp
bin_program_DEPENDENCIES = lib/libYOURLIB.a
bin_program_LDADD = lib/libYOURLIB.a
```

Renaming the files is optional (you could always just `include src/Makefile.am`), but it helps to denote that it isn't meant to be a standalone Automake source file.

Also, supposing that `lib/library.cpp` and `src/main.cpp` both `#include "library.hpp"`, and it's in another directory, you might also want to use `AM_CPPFLAGS = -I $(top_srcdir)/include` for all files or `obj_program_CPPFLAGS = -I include` for all source files that are used in building `bin/program`, assuming `library.hpp` is in `program/include`. I'm not sure if `$(top_srcdir)` is right when another project includes your entire `program` source directory in its own `SUBDIRS` variable, but `$(srcdir)` will always refer to the top-level `program` directory in the case of a non-recursive automake, making it perhaps more useful in larger projects that include this package as a component.

Comment: I have modified both `lib/Makefile.am` and `src/Makefile.am` accordingly, but got a complaint about RANLIB, after adding `AC_PROG_RANLIB` to `configure.ac`, I got yet another error `No rule to make target ../../src/../lib/libtest.a`

Comment: So far my workaround was moving `lib` to `src/lib` and just modifying `src/Makefile.am` => `program_SOURCES = main.cpp lib/library.cpp`

Comment: @Daveel It seems obvious to me now why that happened, but at the time, I didn't realize that would happen at all. I've edited my comment to explain the other options you have.